# Azure Web Role and Codeigniter

Tags: php, web-applications, azure, codeigniter-2

I have written a web app in codeigniter and it uses PHP 5.3.

I have looked at web roles in azure, but it strikes me as not being flexible. For example, it is not so easy to install new dlls and to mess with the server etc.

Is it better to run PHP on a virtual machine on azure or use a web role?

Comment: the whole idea behind the web role is so you don't have to mess with the server. I wouldn't bother with Azure if you are going to run your web app in a vm.

Comment: Sure, but it hasn't got great support for Codeigniter, white labelling and features such as that

Answer (score 1):

Have you looked into [Windows Azure Web Sites](https://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/home/scenarios/web-sites/)? Some of the benefits for your scenario:

- PHP 5.3 is installed by default
- Deployments are quick and flexible [FTP, Git, GitHub, BitBucket]
- [Configuration is simple](https://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/develop/php/common-tasks/configure-php-web-site/)
- Environment setup can be scripted using [cross-platform command line tools](https://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/downloads)